# UWP AudioGraph AudioFileInputNode change pitch

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, soundeffect

How to change pitch in node of `AudioGraph` in UWP app?

I'm trying to port the application from WP7 to uwp (Windows 10, Mobile).
in my WP7 app i use code:

```
SoundEffect soundEffect = //...(load sound effect).
SoundEffectInstance soundInstance = soundEffect.CreateInstance();
soundInstance.Pitch = pitch;
```

How to do it in UWP with `AudioGraph`?

Answer (score 0):

You should share a little more of your code so far, but you want to use the PlaybackSpeedFactor property, which is included on the AudioFileInputNode:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.audio.audiofileinputnode.playbackspeedfactor

Currently, Microsoft's GitHub has the best examples of using AudioGraph:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation/cs/AudioCreation

In the FilePlayback scenario from that last link, all you have to do is add this line to double the pitch of your audio file:

```
 fileInput.PlaybackSpeedFactor = 2;
```

You can make this change in real-time from anywhere in the program (e.g., have a slider that controls playback speed). This won't be a problem at all for AudioGraph. You can *probably* also play stuff backwards by settings this value negative!

Comment: I want to change the pitch without changing the speed. Since it worked in WP7.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to take the AudioFrame data run it through a Fourier Tranform, Multiply the pitches by some factor and then run it back through the Fourier Transform.

Here's some code for getting the frame

Where you define your graph
`graph.QuantumStarted += Graph_QuantumStarted;`

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("5B0D3235-4DBA-4D44-865E-8F1D0E4FD04D")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]

unsafe interface IMemoryBufferByteAccess
{
    void GetBuffer(out byte* buffer, out uint capacity);
}

private static void Graph_QuantumStarted(AudioGraph sender, object args)
{
    AudioFrame frame = frameOutputNode.GetFrame();
    using (AudioBuffer buffer = frame.LockBuffer(AudioBufferAccessMode.Write))
    using (IMemoryBufferReference reference = buffer.CreateReference())
    {
        //Run Fourier and Adjust here
    }
}
```